# devise custom routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

When user goes to

> /account/edit

click submit button it redirects to

> /signup

path ? Any help will be appreciated.

routes

```
devise_for :users, :skip => [:registrations, :sessions] do
  get 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration
  post 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
  get 'users/cancel' => 'devise/registrations#cancel', :as => :cancel_user_registration
  get 'account/edit' => 'devise/registrations#edit', :as => :edit_user_registration
  put 'account' => 'devise/registrations#update'
  delete 'users' => 'devise/registrations#destroy'

  get 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#new', :as => :new_user_session
  post 'signin' => 'devise/sessions#create', :as => :user_session
  get 'signout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy', :as => :destroy_user_session
end
```

registrations/edit.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
<% if resource.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <ul>
      <% resource.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
    <%= f.label :email %><br/>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :password_confirmation %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :current_password %><br/>
  <%= f.password_field :current_password %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
  <%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

Comment: It is posting to /signup.. What is the desired behaviour supposed to be?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there are two possible solutions for this.

**Solution #1:**

Change this line:

```
post 'signup' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
```

To this:

```
post 'account' => 'devise/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration
```

**Solution #2:**

Change this line:

```
put 'account' => 'devise/registrations#update'
```

To this:

```
put 'account' => 'devise/registrations#update', :as => :update_user_registration
```

And then change the form_for url option in the view:

```
form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => update_user_registration_path, :html => { :method => :put })
```